# Android NDK wifi example

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I want to use features of  WIFI with the help of c code by using NDK in android. I don't want to use Java API for WIFI. I tried on Google as well as on stackoverflow, but I didn't got any example for it. I am just wondering , let me know is it possible or not ?

I have found some android API for [WIFI](http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/wifi_8h-source.html). but I haven't any knowledge of implementation.

Comment: What features of wifi do you want to use?

Comment: I want to use WIFI turn On, SSID Search and connect to specific SSID.

Comment: That's not possible in C code. But you can call Java code from C code with help of JNI.

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna look at libcurl, but not quite sure.
Because I am developing games using cocos2d-x (which is using android ndk), and libcurl is the network implementation in cocos2d-x framework, so i guess that might help.

Comment: libcurl can manage connections to url directions, but you need to have the connection with the net already established.