# Is there any low-level API for Wi-Fi?

Tags: android, android-wifi

Since there is no [tethering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023226/android-2-2-wifi-hotspot-api) in API, maybe there is some low level API to control behaviour of Wi-Fi radio?

More general, question is **is it possible to manually control Wi-Fi radio, i.e. send\recieve packets?**

Comment: @themilkman I hope so. But where can I find it exactly?

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779414/android-ndk-wifi-example